# Help me with Boot USB menu

Tags: boot, usb, menu

I had windows 8.1 in my system, then i made a clean install of ubuntu 14.
I installed this ubuntu 14 from USB.
Now I am interested in installing ubuntu mate 15 (using UNebootin).
BUT I find no USB boot menu in the list of priority.
please help.

Comment: This sounds like a question about the BIOS/EFI on your computer. If it is then if we are going to help we need the make/model of your PC before we can help. My first recommendation, however, is if you have a blank DVD on hand, that will generally work on a majority of computers while some older computers will have no way of booting from USB without using a bootstrap on a floppy or CD

Answer (score 0):

If you want Ubuntu MATE 15.10, you can just upgrade to that. You don't need to reinstall. Even if you have the normal Ubuntu 14.04 now, you can install MATE over what you have.

To upgrade from an LTS release (I'm assuming you're using 14.04 and not 14.10), you need to let Ubuntu check for any new release to upgrade to instead of just LTS releases. Open the **Update Manager** app by searching for it. Once that opens, click the **Settings...** button in the bottom left corner. Go to the **Updates** tab and change **Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:** from **For long-term support versions** to **For any new version**. Now, press the **Close** button and put in your password.

Back in the **Update Manager** app, press the **Check** button and let it check for new updates. Once that finishes, press **Install Updates**, put in your password, and let the updates install. You may need to reboot. If that is the case, do it and open the **Update Manager** app again.

Now, press the **Upgrade** button near the top right, next to the message saying **"New Ubuntu release '**.**' is available"**. Your computer should start the upgrade to 15.10. There are some menus you will have to click through during the upgrade process, so don't start it and leave.

If you need images, here is a guide for upgrading 12.04 to 12.10. The steps should still apply: https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12.04-lts-precise-pangolin-to-12.10-quantal-quetzal-desktop-and-server

Now, once you are in 15.10, you need to install the MATE desktop environment, assuming you're not currently using MATE. To do that, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and run `sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment`.

After this, you should be done, and using 15.10 MATE.

---

If you still want to go the USB method:
It sounds like you're in the BIOS setup, trying to change the boot priority and put the USB stick first. That is unnecessary. Instead, you can just press the key to get into the boot menu and select the USB stick from there. Since you didn't provide much about even which version of Ubuntu you want, I can't tell you what that key is. For most computers, it is F12, but that can vary a lot.